# Inverting transformation $\displaystyle m(t)=\sum_{i=1}^d x(i)^t$

Tags: z-transform, laplace-transform

Suppose there's a vector of $d$ of positive numbers $x(1),\ldots,x(d)$ which I need to obtain from a vector of $d$ derived quantities $m(t_1),\ldots,m(t_d)$ where $\{t_i\}$ is some conveniently chosen vector of real numbers and

$$m(t)=\sum_{i=1}^d x(i)^t$$

Is there a practical way to obtain $x$ from $m$? For instance, suppose $x=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{1000})$.

There's related discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4662459/998) which suggests there isn't, which seems unexpected because if we had integrals in place of sums, we could use the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: So that $m(t_1) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^d x(i)^{t_1}$?

Comment: Yes $m(t_1)=\sum_{i=1}^d x(i)^{t_1}$

Comment: Are the t integers?, i.e. $t \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: The $t_i$ values are reals (if I'm reading the question correctly).

Comment: Consider $d=2$, $t_1 = 0$ and $t_2 = 1$. Assume $m(t_1) = 2$ and $m(t_2) = 3$. Then, both $x(1) = 1,\, x(2) = 2$ and $y(1) = 1.5,\, y(2) = 1.5$ are solutions. This is easy to see, so I feel I'm missing something. Maybe the vector $\lbrace t \rbrace$ is not arbitrary?

Comment: For this choice of $t_i$ it seems not possible to recover original vector. If you choose $t=(1,2,3,\ldots,d)$ then this (completely impractical) [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4662746/998) recovers original signal. The formula involves solving a large polynomial, but I'm curious if there's a better choice of $t$ and whether some discrete transform can be used instead of polynomial solver